# udev cdrom rules failing to run scripts

Tags: udev

The following is my rules file in /etc/udev/rules.d/10-autodvd.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sr0", ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_DVD}=="1", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/makemkv.sh sr0"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sr1", ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_DVD}=="1", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/makemkv.sh sr1"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sr2", ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_DVD}=="1", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/makemkv.sh sr2"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sr3", ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_DVD}=="1", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/makemkv.sh sr3"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sr4", ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_DVD}=="1", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/makemkv.sh sr4"
```

It seems to be really hit or miss on actually running the scripts, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Udev sorts the rules files lexically, and at the time your rules are applied, the `ID_CDROM_MEDIA_DVD` variable probably isn't set yet. This is the case on a default install of systemd udev. The `ID_CDROM*` variables are set in `60-cdrom_id.rules`, so you should rename your rules file to sort after this.

Note that you're not supposed to start a long running program with the RUN+= key.

> ```
>    RUN{type}
>    [...]
>        This can only be used for very short-running
>        foreground tasks. Running an event process for
>        a long period of time may block all further
>        events for this or a dependent device.
>
>        Starting daemons or other long-running
>        processes is not appropriate for udev; the
>        forked processes, detached or not, will be
>        unconditionally killed after the event handling
>        has finished.
> ```

Your rules may be written as one rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sr[0-4]", ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_DVD}=="1", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/makemkv.sh %k"
```